# Paypal Express Errors 10413

Tags: paypal

I'm newbie in PayPal express, and the functions return error 10413. 
The client see this bill:

```
1.Item   Price: 77€
2.Item 2 Price:79€

Subtotal: 128.93€ (without tax)
Shipping: 3.95€ (without tax)
TAX:      27.83€(Item's tax + shipping's tax)
Discount: -31.2€

Total to pay:   129.58€
```

In CallShortcutExpressCheckout I do this string:

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=129.58
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&RETURNURL=http://example.com/FinalizarPedido
&CANCELURL=http://example.com/DetalleCarrito
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR
&INVOICEID=63f958d2dc0c08ae6d71059ff90eae22
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Item
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=77.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Item 2
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=79.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=129.58
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=27.83
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=156
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=3.95
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=31.20
SetExpressCheckout
```

Where is the error? Maybe I've to put the item price without tax in `&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0`?

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem, only needed a minus sign first the discount amount

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-31.20
```

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

The 10413 API response means that the ItemTotal, ShippingTotal, HandlingTotal, and TaxTotal do not add up to the value of the OrderTotal that was submitted.  For the rules of this calculation, see the PayPal Integration Guides.

Just from quickly looking at what you supplied, it does not appear you have the totals added correctly.  Looks like PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=156 should be PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=156.58.  Below is the request I just submitted, and it went through.

API Request:

```
USER=xxxxxxxxx   
PWD=xxxxxxxxx   
SIGNATURE=xxxxxxxxx   
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout   
VERSION=98.0   
RETURNURL=https://www.ccaples.com/index.php/api-s/paypal-nvp/nvp-quick-test   
CANCELURL=https://www.ccaples.com/index.php/api-s/paypal-nvp/nvp-quick-test   
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR   
INVOICEID=63f958d2dc0c08ae6d71059ff90eae22   
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Item   
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=77.00   
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1   
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Item 2   
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=79.00   
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1   
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=156.00   
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=156.58   
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=27.83   
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=3.95   
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-31.20
```

API Response:

```
TOKEN=EC-6FP13377V8467513R  
TIMESTAMP=2013-05-06T14:05:04Z  
CORRELATIONID=8f418e8a77fec  
ACK=Success  
VERSION=98.0  
BUILD=5817241
```

Comment: First thanks PP_MTS_Chad but if you see the bill the client dont pay 156, he pays 129.58€ not 156€ these is the item amount with tax. Maybe I dont explain well.

Comment: You would need to adjust your discount amount to be higher than if you are wanting the buyer to pay 129.58.